# Trying to use joins in SSAS Cubes but they dont seem to be working

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-2014, cube, olap-cube

I am preparing a cube in **SSAS** and have am facing an issue with data mismatch in the cube. Essentially, my aim is to get the count of a variable which is the result of a join. When I write a join query in SQL on the same data, I am getting the correct result. But when I am trying to replicate the same into a cube, the results change. 
Below is the query that I have written (and which works).

```
select p.abc, p.rty, m.pqr, m.asd
    from table1.fgh p
    inner join summary.jkl m
    ON p.abc = m.pqr
    where m.asd = 'abcdefg'
    and m.year= '2018'
```

*In the output, I can see 1 row and hence, if I would take the count of it, it would also be 1. Not pasting the count query here as its not required at the moment.*

But when I see the result in the cube, the count is much more. I am pretty sure that the count should be 1 and hence, I am assuming that the join query is not working properly in the cube.
In the data source view, I have taken the following while assigning the relationship:-

```
*Source (foreign key) table= p
Destination (primary key) table= m
Source Columns= abc
Destination Columns= pqr*
```

I have also tried interchanging (reverse) the primary and foreign key tables, but the result is the same.

If someone can help me in this, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: How are you simulating that WHERE clause in the cube?

Comment: In the cube browser, I am using the filter expression option. First I selected a DImension, then selected the hierarchy, then a "Equal" operator and finally specified the variable used in the where clause in the filter expression option.